# ReactJS - react-router-dom Router not rendering google maps Component's DOM though the code is executed without issues

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-router-dom

M basically new to react , so I was trying to create a small google maps integration app. I did manage to do it by calling the `componentDidMount()` which does all the gmaps processing after the `<div id='map'/>` is loaded. All was working fine till this.
Now when I added react-dom-render to add some routes. There is simply nothing
on the screen.
Here is my setup

> index.js

```
const routes=(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Main/>
  </BrowserRouter>)
ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('root'));
```

> Main.js

```
export default class Main extends React.Component{
render (){
    return(
        <main>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/' component={App}/>
            </Switch>
        </main>
    )
}
```

}

> App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
let map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 13.0827, lng: 80.2707},
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
});
render() {
return (

  <div id='app'>
    <div id='map' />
  </div>)
  }
} }
```

So if I run this and up the server I get a blank screen(In the dev console I can see everything that should happen under the hood is happening).
Just FYI
 If I do this to the index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

i.e simply render the App component. All is fine.
Can someone throw some light or am I missing something !
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but might help someone else. Issue might be with your css. Are you getting a warning **"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html"**?

If so, place `<base href="/">`  in your html header.